# Scala program to Java 8 program conversion

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have started learning Apache Spark. Now the tutorials are mostly written in Scala. I want to try the programs in Java 8 also.

But I could not find equivalent coding in Java 8 for few of Scala code.

The Scala code is as follows :

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
   
    val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]", "<class-name>")
       
    val lines = sc.textFile("../a.data")
    val stars = lines.map(x => x.toString().split("\t")(2))
    val results = ratings.countByValue()
    val sortedResults = results.toSeq.sortBy(_._1)
    sortedResults.foreach(println)
  }
```

The equivalent code in Java 8 I have written is :

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext("local[*]", "<class-name>");
        JavaRDD<String> lines = sc.textFile("../a.data");
        
        //....
}
```

The remaining part of the code, I m not able to convert. I could not find equivalent of map function in Java 8. There is one flatmap, but it creates a number of instances.

I tried several other approaches, but they're not working.

The data in the file is in format:

```
191 241 4   654258949
186 312 1   991123772
```

Comment: The Java API is fairly similar to scala.  Take a look at the Docs for JavaRDD, it has all the same methods you need.

Comment: Yes you are right. But if I could get help with first program, I can then get started. I m also looking into online examples, but no luck.

Comment: I think you can write something fairly similar to `val stars = lines.map(x => x.toString().split("\t")(2))` using Java 8's `map`.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow this does the trick. Not sure, if I have coded efficiently or not.

```
sc.textFile("../a.data")
        .map(text -> Arrays.asList(text.split("\t")[2]))
        .mapToPair(word -> new Tuple2<>(word, 1))
        .reduceByKey((a, b) -> a + b)
        .foreach(result -> System.out.println(
            String.format("Word [%s] count [%d].", result._1(), result._2)));
```